# Logarithmic analog to additive map

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was wondering if there was a name for a map analogous to the [additive map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_map) satisfying
$$f(ab)=f(a)+f(b)$$
defined over a ring, module, or other structure akin to the $\log$ function on real numbers and if there were any interesting properties that this map has.

Comment: Logarithms are kinda tricky to deal with, because as soon as you leave the positive real numbers, it becomes multi-valued. So you have to choose a branch-cut, which usually means the additive law is violated for some inputs. The inverse function $x\to\exp(x)$ is much nicer behaved and satisfies $\exp(a+b)=\exp(a)\exp(b)$ for all complex numbers. If you are interested in generalizations of the exponential, you might want to check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula .

Comment: If you really want logarithms, there is for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm , which is a (computationally) very hard problem related to integer factorization (and important in crypography).